# We don't need to [ace.js]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request, retag-request

There is unused [ace.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ace.js) and more used [ace-editor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ace-editor).

I retagged all [ace.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ace.js) question to later one. Can we delete [ace.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ace.js) now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [ace.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ace.js) tag got re-created and was appearing on a couple of questions, so I've now merged and synonymized it with [ace-editor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ace-editor).

This is the preferred option over manual removal when the tag is actually a synonym for a valid, existing tag because it prevents the tag from being recreated. It is also easier and less disruptive.